# Python Pandas: Split by pattern (across rows) in a specific column of DataFrame

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, split

Very new to coding and python, so please bear with me. I have looked and looked but have not been able to find a solution anywhere for this.

I have a dataframe from a large excel spreadsheet where in the 'Tracer gas type' column (in random rows) there is a pattern of continuous '1', '2', '1', '2'... emerging. Those rows need to split from the rest of the spreadsheet. An example section of the dataframe:

```
   df = {'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 'col2': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'],
                  'Tracer gas type': ['1', '2', '1', '1', '0', '1', '2', '1', '2' ]}
        df = pd.DataFrame(data=df)
```

The pattern always starts with 1, may repeat an unknown number of times and finishes on 2. In this example, if correctly split, the new df should only contain the first 2 rows and the last 4 rows of the old df:

As a starting point, I have been able to split the dataframe where values are '1', but have not been able to split the '1', '2', '1', '2'... sections with this method:

```
        self.new_df = self.df[self.df['Tracer gas type'] == '1']
```

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, could you please try to keep a focus on a specific code part, thx

Comment: @PV8 thank you- rewritten for more specific code part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there is a fancy simple way directly with pandas but you could do it like that with basic python iterating over all rows of the dataframe like this:

```
# create a new empty dataset
df_new_data = {
    'col1': []
    , 'col2': []
    , 'Tracer gas type': []
}

last_tgt = ''
this_tgt = ''
# go over all rows in df.values
for row_id in range(0, len(df.values)):
    this_tgt = df.iloc[row_id][2]
    # leave out the first row for comparison
    if(last_tgt != ''): 
        # if the last tgt was 1 and this is 2 then write both rows to the new dataset
        if(this_tgt == '2' and last_tgt == '1'): 
            # print(str(row_id-1) + ' - ' + str(row_id)) # just for debugging
            df_new_data['col1'].append(df.iloc[row_id-1][0])
            df_new_data['col2'].append(df.iloc[row_id-1][1])
            df_new_data['Tracer gas type'].append(df.iloc[row_id-1][2])
            df_new_data['col1'].append(df.iloc[row_id][0])
            df_new_data['col2'].append(df.iloc[row_id][1])
            df_new_data['Tracer gas type'].append(df.iloc[row_id][2])
    # remember this value as 'last value'
    last_tgt = this_tgt

# create new DataFrame from dataset
df_new = pd.DataFrame(df_new_data)
df_new
```

It may be not the prettiest way but it will create the desired result you gave as example.

Comment: I'm using your code but appending to an empty dataframe (made as below) instead of a dataset so columns do not have to be copied individually. 

df_new = pd.DataFrame().reindex_like(df)
        df_new= df_new.iloc[0:0]

 This is exactly what I was stuck on and your code works brilliantly, thank you so very much! I was completely stuck on this and I really appreciate the time you spent on this :)